# Mysql field delete all characters after 8th character

Tags: mysql, sql, string, date, sql-update

I have one field in a table that has a time as a value.

table name: sessions
column: time

For example

```
time
-----
09:00:00 (this should be the correct time)

12:00:00:00:00

09:00:00:00

11:00:00:00:00:00:00

16:00:00:00:00
```

This table got messed up and I would like to clean it and keep only the 8 first characters of each row and delete everything that is after that.

Is there a way i can do this with a mysql command?

Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Use string functions:

```
update mytable set mytime = substring(mytime, 1, 8)
```

I would also recommend changing the datatype of your column to `time`, so the database will properly enforce data integrity for you in the future. If your data can be implicitely converted to the target format (which should be the case once after executing the above query), you can just do:

```
alter table mytable modify mytime time;
```

Note that `time` is not a wise choice for a column name, since it conflicts with a MySQL datatype. I used `mytime` instead in the queries.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to update the table:

```
update sessions
set time = left(time, 8)
```